# Move "Moov" atom to the top in Java

Tags: java, android, video-encoding, android-mediarecorder

Is there any way to move "moove" atom of a H264 encoded mp4 video to the top, using java in Android?

Android mediarecorder put "moov" atom at the end of the file by default.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/559372/using-ffmpeg-to-locate-moov-atom

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want use NDK. I'm looking for a solution in pure java.